# part of list in div

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have a list:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     Animals
     <ul>
       <li>tiger</li>
       <li>lion</li>
       <li>cow</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     Birds
     <ul>
       <li>owl</li>
       <li>parrot</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     Flowers
     <ul>
       <li>rose</li>
       <li>lily</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I need to change the background on animals and birds so it looks like solid piece.
I tried to put it into div like this:

```
<ul>
   <div id='foo'>
   <li>
     Animals
     <ul>
       <li>tiger</li>
       <li>lion</li>
       <li>cow</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     Birds
     <ul>
       <li>owl</li>
       <li>parrot</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   </div>
   <li>
     Flowers
     <ul>
       <li>rose</li>
       <li>lily</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But it wasn't working. 
I want to have it in solid rectangle. 
Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: A) Please show us some CSS or explain your expected outcome a bit better
B) You cannot put a `<div>` as a direct child of a `<ul>`. The only acceptable direct child of a `<ul>` is `<li>`

Comment: I need to have like a one solid rectangle under area with this part of list.

Comment: If I would apply css on li it would change backround only around words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the list both birds and animals lists I put under one li, to which I applied style.

Thanks everyone for pointing me there! :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<ul>
   <li class="animal>
     Animals
     <ul">
       <li>tiger</li>
       <li>lion</li>
       <li>cow</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="animal>
     Birds
     <ul>
       <li>owl</li>
       <li>parrot</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     Flowers
     <ul>
       <li>rose</li>
       <li>lily</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:
Set them a width, so they will be all the same width

```
.animal 
{
   width:200px;
   background-color:green;

}
```

Comment: It would change background, only under words. and it would look like two separated rectangles. I need to have like a one solid rectangle under area with that part of the list

Comment: Can you try this plz Also, you could play with the margin to make the 2 rectangles together

Comment: No, I'm sorry. but this is still not what I need. This still will make two separated rectangles. because those parts of the list are different long....

Comment: even if you set them the same width and height? I think it's just a bad way to represent what you need then. Can I give you a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Use CCS class styles and apply them to your `<li>` element. Placing other types of elements within a list is not valid HTML.

CSS:

```
.mystyle {
    /* Whatever */
}
```

Markup:

```
<li class="mystyle"></li>
```

Comment: It would change background, only under words. and it would look like couple rectangles glued together. I need to have like a one solid rectangle under area with this list

Comment: I disagree. You should be able to play with borders, margins, display settings, etc. to get it to look exactly as you want. And if you really want to cover the entire list, you can set the style of the `<ul>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `div` element in UL but you can do it with 2 ways:

1) Manually set a css class to bird and animal:

```
<ul>
   <li class='someBackground'>
     Animals
     <ul>
       <li>tiger</li>
       <li>lion</li>
       <li>cow</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='someBackground'>
     Birds
     <ul>
       <li>owl</li>
       <li>parrot</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     Flowers
     <ul>
       <li>rose</li>
       <li>lily</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

2) Use CSS3 selectors:

```
ul li:nth-child(1),ul li:nth-child(2) {
    //your css code
}
```

Comment: It would change background, only under words. and it would look like couple rectangles glued together.
I need to have like a one solid rectangle under area with this list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
   <li id="animals">
     Animals
     <ul>
       <li>tiger</li>
       <li>lion</li>
       <li>cow</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="birds">
     Birds
     <ul>
       <li>owl</li>
       <li>parrot</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     Flowers
     <ul>
       <li>rose</li>
       <li>lily</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#animals, #birds {
background:green;
}
```

Comment: It would change background, only under words. and it would look like two separated rectangles. I need to have like a one solid rectangle under area with this list